# How can I connect PCI card with laptop

Tags: laptop, pci

I am working on image-based herbicide applicator. I used LabVIEW software for image processing and PCI card was used and connected CPU. In lab it is working well but, when I was working in the field due to vibration of the tractor system got trouble and unable to process data.

My question is here how can I replace CPU and monitor with laptop. I want to attach PCI card with laptop.

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear what your problem is. Why do you expect the PCI card to work better if your problem is vibrations?

Comment: Some laptops have Expresscard slots and you can get adaptors to go to PCIe or PCI, that *might* be an option but I'm not too sure if it would definitely work.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but not just any laptop:  Your laptop has to have a PCIE (PCI-Express) expansion slot or a Thunderbolt slot.

In the former case, you can get a [PCIE to PCI converter](https://superuser.com/questions/46956/can-i-turn-a-pci-e-x1-slot-into-an-old-pci-slot)

In the latter one you can get one of the multiple Thunderbolt to PCI adapters and do it that way.

**However** before you go spend a lot of money you have to think about what [Seth](https://superuser.com/questions/1316771/how-can-i-connect-pci-card-with-laptop#comment1960718_1316771) said in his comment:

> Sorry but it's not clear what your problem is. Why do you expect the PCI card to work better if your problem is vibrations?

Answer (score 0):

In the year 2021 this is definitely possible thanks to Thunderbolt 3 PCIe expansion devices such as this: [OWC Mercury Helios 3S Thunderbolt 3 PCIe Expansion Solution](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/HELIOS3S/)

Of course this all hinges on the laptop having a Thunderbolt 3 connection, but they are more and more common nowadays on PCs and pretty much all MacBooks and Mac minis.

Look at the backside of this thing; it can handle PCI cards no problem.

[image: Ports on the OWC Mercury Helios 3S Thunderbolt 3 PCIe Expansion]

This is all possible because [Thunderbolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)) is effectively designed to be PCIe over a small wire:

> “Thunderbolt combines PCI Express (PCIe) and DisplayPort (DP) into two serial signals, and additionally provides DC power, all in one cable. Up to six peripherals may be supported by one connector through various topologies.”